# spark embedded (same JVM) for <400k text file process

Tags: apache-spark

Can we do a mini spark job embedded in our app? Any example? Reason : want to process part of a file and give results quicker than submitting a regular job. File is only 500 lines. But do not want to keep 2 code bases - just the one that is used for the large files too. File size is less than an MB.

I want to process the file in the same JVM that my client code is running. Want a single executor kicked off from within same JVM, via a flag in the config. (so a few jobs will have this flag set and others wont. Those that do not will run as usual on the cluster.)